# how to join 3 relational tables

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

how to join 3 relational tables with the structure:

```
t1 | id
t2 | id | rating
t3 | source_id | relation
```

t3 stores the data of a field which t1 and t2 uses both. so source_id field can be t1's id or t2's id.

```
input  : t1 id
output : t2 rating
```

an example:

```
**t1**

id |
---------
42 |

**t2**

id | rating  
-------------
37 | 9.2

**t3**

id | source_id
--------------
42 | 1
37 | 1
26 | 2
23 | 1
```

what i want is to get 9.2 output with 42 input.

can you do that in one sql query?

Comment: What is the meaning of `source_id`? It is `1` for both `42` and `37`, though they belong to different tables.

Comment: Your table structure is unclear. `source_id` does not appear to do what you describe. For the joins you want, there should be a relation containing the tuple (42,37).

Comment: I also didnt get it. And why should the output for 42 be 9.2? Isnt 9.2 related to 37? // Oh, i think i got it. The output for 42, 37 and 23 should be 9.2. Is it?

Comment: @Michael no. 9.2 can only be the output of 42. as you can see 37 is an item of t2, and 23 is some other tables item.

Comment: 42 in no way is related to 9.2.  either your question is incorrect, or your data model is incorrect.  i suspect both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query will give you the desired output on your data, though don't think it's correct in your model:

```
SELECT  t2.rating
FROM    t1
JOIN    t3 t31
ON      t31.id = t1.id
JOIN    t3 t32
ON      t32.source_id = t31.source_id
JOIN    t2
ON      t2.id = t32.id
WHERE   t1.id = 42
```

Comment: you are right about the source_id, it is not clear but it doesn't have to also. as you can imagine, if source id is 1, than 42 and 37 is connected.

Comment: @orioncabbar: what if you have id `42` both in `t1` and in `t2`?

Comment: actually, it is possible but it doesn't matter for me, i just want one result, so limit it with one. by the way i tryied your solution, it gave a resukt but a wrong one. i am trying to understand how is it possible.

Comment: @Quassnoi yes, your solution brings a result but a wrong one. ?!

Comment: @orioncabbar: try now. Also, "wrong one" is not very descriptive.

Comment: yes @Quassnoi it works and your solution is way elegant then mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You "relational tables" are a disaster; the SQL code (SQL is designed to navigate Relational Databases) required will be a further disater, never complete or stable.  Coding issues are consequential, second order problems, which identify errors in the first order.

First, normalise and model your data accurately for the Relational DBMS that you have placed it in; and so that you can use the SQL Relational Language.  Then the code will be simple, easy, straight-forward and complete.

If you want me to model the data, fine.  But I need more information than cryptic `Id` columns; I need names of entities and columns, what they mean, how they are actually related to each other.

**Responses to Comments**

Yes, you certainly can have a column that is a Foreign Key referencing more than one parent table.  But you cannot (in the Relational Database) have a column that is a *either* one *or* another parent table: that will lead to orphans, spinsters, and all kinds of easily avoidable coding horrors.

Comment: +1 This really needs to be said.  There's almost never a reason to have a "foreign key" column that can point to two different tables.  That usually indicates bad design or incomplete normalization.  It's often tempting when trying to implement OO in an RDBMS.  But there are still better ways after a little bit of tought.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean with the clarification.  That's clearly not what's going on here, though.

Comment: @siride. *That's clearly not what's going on here* Not sure what you mean: the first part of my response is **not** going on here; the second part **is** going on here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.  Such is the danger of using pronouns :).

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution, what do you think?

```
SELECT t2.rating
FROM t3 AS t3
inner join t1 AS t1 on t1.id = t3.id
inner join (SELECT source_id, rating
FROM t3 AS t32
inner join t2 AS review on t2.id = t32.id) as second on second.source_id = t3.source_id
where t1.id = 42 limit 0,1
```

Comment: Answering your own question and voting for yourself is always suspicious.  Is this a real question or a cryptic puzzle about non-relational non-tables.